# Redirecting after a login to the original task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

So I want to send emails to users with some links which you can click on to do things, but if the user isn't already logged in, I'd like to be able to let the user log in and then redirect him back to what he was trying to get to.

I have these methods in application_controller.rb

This is called as a before_filter on the place the URL links to, catches that the user shouldn't be wherever he is trying to go and stores the intent

```
    def user_in_beta
    unless user_signed_in? && current_user.beta
      if user_signed_in?
        redirect_to :home_betawait
      else 
        session[:original_uri] = request.request_uri
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
      end
    end
  end
```

And this should catch him after he signs in and put him back where he belongs.

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    if current_user.beta
      if session[:original_uri].nil?
        :home_index
      else
        session[:original_uri]
      end
    else :home_betawait
    end
  end
```

However, it does not. Instead I get a very nasty "cannot redirect to nil!" If I read it into a local variable and store it, even more things break.  I am very baffled, this has to be an extremely common thing to want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to let the user
>   log in and then redirect him back to
>   what he was trying to get to.

This behavior is already provided by Devise's `authenticate_user!` before_filter. Since your "devise" tag on this story and use of `user_signed_in?` suggest that you are already using Devise why reinvent your own solution?