# get original url during signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When a user who isn't signed in hits a url, devise will forward them to the sign-in page, after which it will forward the user on to their original page.  How can I access this information (the original route/action) in the sign-in view?  I'd like to show the gui differently depending on where the user is going.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirecting after a login to the original task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5359195/redirecting-after-a-login-to-the-original-task)

Comment: @Jordan This is not a duplicate.  Devise correctly sends the user on to the right webpage.  I just want to know *what that page will be*.  The question you linked to does not ask for this and the answer does not address it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you should extend/override devise's sessions controller. To do this, copy the latest `new` action code from [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb), and paste it in a controller (let's call it sessions) that inherits from devise's sessions controller, like this:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    self.resource = build_resource(nil, :unsafe => true)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    @after_sign_in_url = after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end
end
```

Since this controller inherits from Devise's, when an action isn't defined in your controller that action will be processed by Devise's controller. So you only have to override that `new` action.

Finally, edit your routes file so this change takes effect:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' }
```

Alternatively, if you are using a scope, like this:

```
# routes.rb
devise_scope :user do
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
end
```

You can now access `@after_sign_in_url` in your view!

Comment: where do i call this?  in devise's new.html.erb it throws `undefined method 'after_sign_in_path_for'`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more thorough. Hope this helps.